# Text file to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, text

I have a Text file contains table contents such as following:

```
 |ID    |SN| | Date | Code |Comp|Source|        Format          |Unit|BuyQTY|DoneQTY|YetQTY|Late

 21C011  5   1080201 BAO-99 高雄  10P056 5X3X5M/R   RBDC-18865LA Ｍ    10000    7000    3000   1                                                                                                                                
 21C006  1   1080201 BAO-99 高雄  20A001 5X8X2M/R 高廠軟 Q 料     Ｍ    60000   40000   20000   1   
 21C002  6   1080201 BAO-99 高雄  10W013 5X1X5M/R PVC+UV         Ｍ   202000  100500  101500      
 21C006  4   1080212 BAO-99 高雄  10P038 4X5X5M/R    DIGI PACK    Ｍ   255000          255000      
 21C006  5   1080212 BAO-99 高雄  10P039 4X6X5M/R    DIGI PACK         295000          295000      
 21C006  6   1080212 BAO-99 高雄  10P040 4X2X5M/R    DIGI PACK    Ｍ   114000          114000      
 21C006  7   1080212 BAO-99 高雄  10P041 4X9X5M/R    DIGI PACK    Ｍ    49500           49500
```

**Notice that there are many missing values and different length in "Format" column.**

I tried to read it into Excel such as following:

[image: Excel Result]

Because of the missing values and different format length, I can NOT just simply use `Split`.

I tried to use `Graphics.MeasureString()` to get the width of the substring between certain lengths.

Such as width between 125 and 140 will be "Unit".

But because of the Chinese characters and spaces, the result are all "crooked"!

I can never get it to the right column!

Could somebody please be so kind and teach me how could I get it done correctly!?

Much appreciated!!!

**Update:**

Because I'm writing a program for **somebody** to do such a task, so I **CAN'T** ask him to modify the original text through NotePad++ or any other software.

I also can **NOT** ask him to import it using Excel and set the column widths!

ALL because of it's for **their convenience**!!!

So I apologize VERY MUCH if I can NOT make life any easier!!!

PS. The Chinese characters are BIG5.

**The following is the code I use to parse the text file into a DataGridView:**

```
float[] colLens = new float[] { 137, 161, 301, 359, 400, 510, 760, 804, 872, 944, 1010, 1035,1050 };
Graphics g = CreateGraphics();

str = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName,Encoding.GetEncoding("BIG5"));
for(int i = 0; i < str.Count(); i++)
{
    int c = 0;
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

    row.CreateCells(dgvMain);
    d = -1;
    for(int j = 1; j < str[i].Length ; j++)
    {
        string s = str[i].Substring(0,  j);
        SizeF size = g.MeasureString(s, new Font("細明體", 12));

        for (int k = d + 1; k < colLens.Count()-1; k++)
        {
            if (size.Width < colLens[k]) break;
            else if(size.Width < colLens[k + 1])
            {
                d = k;
                row.Cells[d].Value = str[i].Substring(c, j - c);
                c = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    dgvMain.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: You can simply use Notepad++ and fill the vertical spaces with any character you like(comma or pipe) after which you can read it in any way using the character as a splitter. You can do that by pressing alt and left mouse click to select vertically.

Comment: Tried to read *how*? Excel can read data both from delimited text (eg csv files) and fixed length data. `Gaphics.MeasureString()` has nothing to do with string processing (as in nothing at all).

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla that would be pointless as Excel can read fixed-length data just fine. Reading parts of a line based on length is a simple call to `String.Substring(start,length)`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does the *actual* file look like? What encoding was used to save it? How did you read it? Chinese characters would need *two* bytes if the file was saved using in a multibyte encoding like GB18030. That would bring the length of all format values to 16 *bytes*.

Comment: Did you try to import into excel using fixed width?  You can move the lines in the excel import and delete the lines in the import GUI in excel.

Comment: PLEASE see the update. Thanks!

Comment: I can read file in easily.  Will do a little later.

Comment: @PiggyChu001 and Big5 *is* a variable-length encoding, which means the `Format` column is precisely 16 *bytes* in all cases. You still haven't posted the code you use to read this file by the way. Worst case, you can read the actual bytes from the file using the field lengths  in bytes and use [Encoding.GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the corresponding string. You can get the Big5 encoding with `Encoding.GetEncoding(950)`

Comment: Your code is filling a grid, not generating or filling an Excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chinese encodings are variable length, whether Big5 or GB18030. This means that `X`is stored as a single byte but `高` is stored as two bytes. It seems that this file has a fixed *byte* length per field, not a fixed character length.

This means that code that expects a fixed *character* length won't be able to read this file easily. That includes Excel and probably every CSV handling library or code.

In the worst case, you can read the bytes directly from a file stream. Each set of bytes can be converted to a string using `Encoding.ToString`. You can get the Big5 encoding with `Encoding.GetEncoding(950)`.

```
Encoding _big5=Encoding.GetEncoding(950);
byte[] _buffer=new byte[90];


public string GetField(FileStream stream,int offset, int length)
{
    var read=stream.ReadBytes(_buffer,offset,length);
    if(read>0)
    {
        return _big5.GetString(buffer,0,read);
    }
    else 
    {
        return "";
    }
}

//Quick & dirty way to skip to end
public void SkipToLineEnd(FileStream stream)
{
    int c;
    while((in=stream.ReadByte()>-1)
    {
        if (c==(int)'\n')
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can construct a record from a line this way :

```
public MyRecord GetNextRecord(FileStream stream)
{
    var record = new MyRecord 
                 {
                     Id=GetField(stream,0,9),
                     ...
                     //6 bytes, not just 4
                     Comp = GetField(stream,28,6),
                     ..
                     //Start from 50, 16 bytes
                     Format =  GetField(stream,50,16)
                 };
        SkipToLineEnd(stream);
        return myRecord;        
}
```

You can write an iterator method that reads records this way until it reaches the end of file. A quick&dirty method to do that would be to check whether the `Position` of the stream is so close to the end that no full record can be produced, eg :

```
public IEnumerable<MyRecord> GetRecords(FileStream stream,int recordLength)
{
    while(stream.Position < stream.Length - recordLength)
    {
        yield return GetRecordNextRecord(stream);
    }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
var records=GetRecords(myStream,96);
foreach(var record in records)
{
    ....
}
```

This will take care of trailing newlines and possibly broken last lines.

To skip the header lines, just call `SkipToLineEnd()` as many times as needed.

You could use a library like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) to generate an Excel file directly from this, eg

```
using (var p = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var ws=p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");
    ws.Cells.LoadFromCollection(records);
    p.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"c:\workbooks\myworkbook.xlsx"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: 
First use "Split" and read from origin up to source column, then from late to unit (note "reverse" order). What is left is format.

IE, if using fixed columns and ONLY format gives problems,

```
var colsIdToSource = line.left(200); //Assuming 200 is the sum of cols up to source
var colsUnitToLate = line.right(150); //idem from unit to late
var formatColumn = line.substring(200, line.length-150); // May need to adjust a char or less
```

Then you process the known columns.

Good luck :)

Comment: Please note this is a pseudocode in c# you can implement in Excel as vb

Comment: This won't work because the length of each line is different! And even if you get to get the substring after "unit", you won't know which column it belong to because of the "missing values"! But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This task is not as easy as it looks.  The code work with posted input.  It may need a little adjustments.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication100
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //|ID    |SN| | Date | Code |Comp|Source|        Format          |Unit|BuyQTY|DoneQTY|YetQTY|Late
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SN", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Comp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Source", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Format", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("BuyQTY", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DoneQTY", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("YetQTY", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Late", typeof(int));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.Unicode);

            string line = "";
            int lineCount = 0;
            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if ((++lineCount > 1) && (line.Trim().Length > 0))
                {
                    string leader = line.Substring(0, 30).Trim();
                    string source = line.Substring(31, 16).Trim();

                    string trailer = line.Substring(48).TrimStart();
                    string format = trailer.Substring(0, 12).TrimStart();
                    trailer = trailer.Substring(12).Trim();

                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();

                    string[] splitLeader = leader.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    newRow["ID"] = splitLeader[0].Trim();
                    newRow["SN"] = splitLeader[1].Trim();
                    newRow["Date"] = splitLeader[2].Trim();
                    newRow["Code"] = splitLeader[3].Trim();
                    newRow["Comp"] = splitLeader[4].Trim();
                    newRow["Source"] = source;
                    newRow["Format"] = format;


                    newRow["Unit"] = trailer.Substring(0,4).Trim();
                    newRow["BuyQTY"] = int.Parse(trailer.Substring(4, 8));

                    string doneQTYstr = trailer.Substring(12, 8).Trim();
                    if (doneQTYstr.Length > 0)
                    {
                        newRow["DoneQTY"] = int.Parse(doneQTYstr);
                    }

                    if (trailer.Length <= 28)
                    {
                        newRow["YetQTY"] = int.Parse(trailer.Substring(20));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newRow["YetQTY"] = int.Parse(trailer.Substring(20,8));
                        newRow["late"] = int.Parse(trailer.Substring(28));
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```